# MVC View giving "An error occurred while processing your request."

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created views in an MVC 5 application using the scaffolding option of "MVC 5 Controllers with views, using Entity Framework". This ties to my Azure hosted DB that the models in my MVC project are using. Once I create the scaffold and try to browse to the index view, it gives me an error in big, bold, red letters as follows:

"An error occurred while processing your request."

Is there way to uncover what the error actually is? Does anyone have a clue why I am getting this error?

Thanks,

K.

Comment: there is some exception coming in your application, turn on RemoteErrors to see what exact exception coming

Comment: Do you mean RemoteOnly in the Web Config?

Comment: yes i mean that, just toggle it

Comment: Its not working. It gives me a runtime error

Comment: Here it is: The model backing the 'TenantDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database

Comment: your EF model and Database are not synced

Comment: try updating your Entity Data Model from Database if Database First Approach

Comment: Thanks, I tried that by updating, but I have the same error. The TenantDbContext is referencing the DefaultConnection and not the Azure DB

Comment: Sorry, the db context error was when trying to view locally. The runtime is at the root when browsing the azure hosted site

Comment: I just recreated the project and ended up with the same error when I try to navigate to my view. Any ideas?

Comment: the error says all your EDM model and database has conflicts recreate the EDM.